# Is short-cut Ctrl-Alt-Esc switched off?

Tags: shortcut-keys

here is 12.04.01 LTS

There is top and kill -9 PID 
but the quicker shortcut is not working like:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>

It is switched off ?

Answer (score 0):

[From this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1602442) it doesn't appear that non-KDE Ubuntu has had that recently.

Nevertheless, in post #7, AIPHEE suggests going to *System Settings* -> *Keyboard* -> *Custom* and adding a shortcut for xkill by entering a new shortcut and assigning it. The key combination you asked about is already used by "Switch system controls directly",  however.